# wget: unable to resolve host address in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, wget

The following command works in google colab.

```
!wget -P "/content/drive/My Drive/data" ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1KB.zip
```

It downloads the data.

However, when I tried downloading multiple files,

```
urls = ["ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1KB.zip",
        "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/512KB.zip"]

for url in urls:
  print (url)

  !wget -P "/content/drive/My Drive/data" url
```

The following error occurs:

```
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘url’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the variable with a `$`.

```
urls = ["ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1KB.zip",
        "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/512KB.zip"]

for url in urls:
  print (url)

  !wget -P "/content/drive/My Drive/data" $url
```